# PullToRefresharp doesn't work on device

Tags: android, xamarin, pull-to-refresh

I have app on Xamarin.Android and I'm using PullToRefresharp in it. It works well on emulators on Pc but it doesn't work on any device. When I'm trying to launch a layout with this component - layout doesn't load at all.

```
<pulltorefresharp.android.views.ViewWrapper 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <pulltorefresharp.android.widget.ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/textAreaScroller"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_x="0px"
                android:layout_y="25px"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="#E6E7E8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
                    <TableLayout
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/archive_table" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </pulltorefresharp.android.widget.ScrollView>
        </pulltorefresharp.android.views.ViewWrapper>
```

Code behind:

```
scrollView = FindViewById<PullToRefresharp.Android.Widget.ScrollView>(Resource.Id.textAreaScroller);
                if (scrollView != null) {
                    scrollView.RefreshActivated += HandleRefreshActivated;
                }

private void HandleRefreshActivated (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            scrollView.OnRefreshCompleted ();
        }
```

May be I didin't set any property. I hope anybody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend for you to use the Android V4 control here a very simple example to use it

First add the Android Support V4 component

XML Implementation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView1" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code Implementation

```
ListView listView = null;
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipe = null;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            listView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);
            swipe = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout> (Resource.Id.swipe1);

            swipe.Refresh += (sender, e) => {
                swipe1.Refreshing = false;
                ReloadDataMethod();
            };

            swipe.SetColorScheme (Android.Resource.Color.HoloBlueBright,
                Android.Resource.Color.HoloGreenLight,
                Android.Resource.Color.HoloOrangeLight,
                Android.Resource.Color.HoloRedLight);
        }
```

its a very simple implementation,
Hope it help you, if you have a question feel free to ask me

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why your code works and his does not, or what his code is missing.

Comment: I prefer to use the native Android Control, i never use the control that he use, but the native control works for me perfectly

Comment: I was trying to use SwipeRefreshLayout as recommended above, but I have error: [mono-rt] android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class swipetorefresh.ScrollChildSwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: This is just the same error when I was trying to use PullToRefresharp.

Comment: Check if you had the Android Support V4 referenced in your project you can download it in the Xamarin Components store